# I need help figuring out what kind of code this is

Tags: decode

I'm not even sure if this is actually code, this subject is very foreign to me, honestly. But in this game I have to solve this puzzle and this thing came up. The first thing that came to mind was base64 (again I'm pretty clueless so I was obviously wrong). I'm sure if I decode(?) the text I will be able to solve the problem.

Here's the code:

KM22tn7TkihR2oOkxcjq fV39RygOl2ZToR1mO07J SDXHNoHEViZkchC2Z2YD 4MefSGGYQ4bc5n2bi6Lb EJp5vNcWeIstwtGaNCTH h9syfTyGpwOqUHFN4U4T 1cjiHmOzKqw73nM3D2Iq Nl18Xpiw8GDuEQq9SgkA UqQJMre8DSq3u49yYjXV x3NgrAnr0uDW3jTB8y04 N6jX9pwxxfDt666jLOHH 2nU1M72TAnn62zlBnTW9 reS9leDj4pk6BqIcjoXp XZNdv1KCeLKbABwiDHgk aBptPCsiB8g7wQ3aUqQC LodqzJzLq0gilChLVvxv YIXXv2vNSmkNcxi57Ia8 1TwZEWrX0HwgzAbYTRO9 0zvJ5l8zdOQRWyenGwOO QQi7bQC0g5XXwAYQNjaY WKCJzDeO6NClyJjyNsDj EU1gZxEmyuppqcJaVvh9 DpHAz5mCMmigc5j1U3bb GYn7zWYlDMOcKUQ2KzEr fWMjSW2l2zTbRCFnEA6I eL8y6OceyHawWpchNdz9 PSRSL6apM0siP9HmK4kv 5rmld0ruTPa1DbtvEWUh QRsnnuPiU7QsaBaWxrtd rg4wTvlSsqL3bsDH6wtd jixudmHlCaYxGx9JAwZP Igrf4CblxVwZYceS4d7P FEKMfXWZwe461kbI0uRL 2RoHtNokBnoGqDQPHHno ppwM2pztH3bBsO6tfQ46 4ZjqsadsPHaoyuN6ou3b UYlz16rTwUTqfddFpZTW wv6G5eLTom4Aqlvy3UDn MVErDnCwepnVPZaptYPO 1RhmiHhLe7mQF9rjeCl7

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this puzzle. Try looking in another directory. ;)

Comment: Ahah hey! I never thought I would have my question answered by the actual game dev! I absolutely adored your game btw! When I posted this question I was really stuck on that but I've finished the game since then, but I still reaaaaally wanna know what this is :c Because I tried everything I could think of and still couldn't figure it out! Atleast I hope it's sth or I'll feel kinda dumb lol